# train_step in Custom training class does not work when upgrading my MacBook from AMD to M1

Tags: macos, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1

I am trying to do a simple custom training loop.

For some reason, the train_step() function gets ignored and a normal training loop is carried. I noticed when the word "Hello" is not printed when I run the script on my MacBook Pro with M1 chip. My old MacBook Pro (AMD) works perfectly and the code also worked perfectly on Google Colab.

The tensor flow version is 2.0.0 and Keras is 2.3.1. Thanks in advance for your help.

My Code is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model

# tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)  
class CustomModel(Model):
    # @tf.function
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data
        print('Hello')

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)
        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
# Construct and compile an instance of CustomModel
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
model = CustomModel(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])

# Just use `fit` as usual
x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
y = np.random.random((1000, 1))
model.fit(x, y, epochs=3)
```

Hello is not printed:
[image: Hello is not printed]
Hello is printed during training:
[image: Hello is printed during training]

Comment: are you sure that you are using compatible versions of TF? maybe one has old releases

Comment: After double checking and re-installation. I have found out that I need to download the tensorflow-deps , tensorflow-macos for it to work. All other versions of TF failed to recognise the training step for some reason. It is working now

Comment: Please consider posting your own answer on how you got this working. Also you may wish to tag this as python and tensorflow. It looks like python.